# Leaks when adding-removing objects to a MutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

i have a memory leak in my app.
My app launches on a tableviewcontroller. i parse a json file to fill an array. Then this array is used to fill the tableview's cells.
I fill my array with objects (class).

I do:

```
[tab_Demandes removeAllObjects];

for (NSDictionary *demandeD in demandes)

{
    Demande *dem =[[Demande alloc] init];

    dem.demTitle=title;

    dem.demId=Id;

    dem.demCreated=created;

    [tab_Demandes addObject:dem];

    [dem release];
}
```

My array and tableview are filled at launch, no problem.
if i hit a  table cell and then want to come back on the tableview my app crash on :

```
[tab_Demandes removeAllObjects];
```

If i dont do [dem release] i have leaks in instruments every time i reload tab_Demandes. RemoveAllObjects works but i have leaks.

Thx for any help as usual.

Wallou
++

Edit : here is where i made my cells. Maybe i mess up when creating the cells
Actually tab_Demandes is declared in the delegate with get/set to access it from other classes (where i load my tableviewcontroller).

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCellViewController *cell = (CustomCellViewController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   // NSLog(@"Cell created");
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellViewController" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCellViewController class]])
        {
            cell = (CustomCellViewController *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

    // Set up the cell...


    TabsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TabsAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    cell.lbl_demId.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] demId]];
    cell.lbl_demCopro .text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demIdCopro ]];
    cell.lbl_demImmeuble.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demIdImmeuble]];
    cell.lbl_demLot.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demIdLot]];
    cell.lbl_demDescriptif.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demTitle]];
    //NSLog(@"statut demande : %@",[[tab_Demandes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demStatut]);
    if ([[[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demStatut] isEqualToString: @"Validée"])
    {
    cell.lbl_ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"VDEM2.png"];
    }
    if([[[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demStatut] isEqualToString: @"Initiée"])
    {
       cell.lbl_ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"IDEM.png"];
    }
    if([[[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demStatut] isEqualToString: @"Terminée"])
    {
    cell.lbl_ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"TDEM.png"];
    }
    if([[[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] demStatut] isEqualToString: @"En coursée"])
    {
    cell.lbl_ImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"EDEM.png"];
    }


return cell;
```

}

NEW EDIT:

Demandes.h:

```
@interface Demande : NSObject { 

    NSString *demId;
    NSString *demStatut;
    NSString *demTitle;
    NSString *demCreated;
    NSString *demIdCopro;
    NSString *demIdImmeuble;
    NSString *demIdLot;
    NSString *demDescriptif;
    NSString *demAuteur;
    NSString *demIdAuteur;
    NSString *demLoginAuteur;   
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demId;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demIdCopro;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demIdImmeuble;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demIdLot;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demDescriptif;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demStatut;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demTitle;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demCreated;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demAuteur;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demIdAuteur;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *demLoginAuteur;
@end
```

Demandes.m:

```
import "Demande.h"
@implementation Demande


@synthesize demId,demIdCopro,demIdImmeuble,demIdLot,demDescriptif,demStatut,demTitle,demCreated,demAuteur,demIdAuteur,demLoginAuteur;


- (void)dealloc {   
    [demId release];
    [demIdCopro release];
    [demId release];
    [demIdImmeuble release];
    [demIdLot release];
    [demDescriptif release];
    [demStatut release];
    [demTitle release];
    [demCreated release];
    [demAuteur release];
    [demIdAuteur release];
    [demLoginAuteur release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the Demande class?

Answer (score 0):

The code above is correct.  I wondering if you don't over release objects that are in you array (i.e. during tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method).  When calling removeAllObject, the method release every object it removes. If one object is already released and deallocated, you app will crash.

**Proposed Optimization :**

-Be sure that the cellIdentifier in the nib is well @"Cell"

-Replace

```
cell.lbl_demId.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] demId]];
```

by

```
Demand* dem = [[[appDelegate tab_Demandes] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
cell.lbl_demId.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dem demId]];
```

to avoid querying the array too much time.

-Avoid placing your model in the appDelegate and create a singleton model object instead.  This is a common beginner design mistake driven by the fact that the appDelegate is an easy object to customize and access to avoid passing you model to every objects.

Comment: i agree with you it has to be this kind of bug. I'll look in the code where i may release it and come back to tell you. Is there a way to "follow" an object while the app is running in order to know when it is released?

Comment: You may override the release method an simply call [super release] then set a breakpoint there.

Comment: there is something strange. if i don't do "removeAllObjects" and still do [dem release] , objects keep adding in the tableview (x2,x3,x4 ... at any reload of the view). BUT i still can read any objects in the array. i just cant delete them.

Comment: its my first app, sorry for the mess. what kind of optimization?

Comment: i come back at you because i havent solved my problem yet. i fill tab_demandes in the appDelegate. I can do removeAllObjects from appDelegate methods but from another class it won't work.

Comment: how have you declare the tab_Demandes property in the appDelegate (nonatomic, retain) ?

Comment: i do: @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tab_Demandes; and @synthesize in the .m . Thx for the help, i saw you are from belgium. id

Comment: Nothing prevent us of doing so but it's clearly not fair !  Also, I suggest that we delete every comments that are not relevant to the question.  So will I. (including this one as soon as you read it)

Comment: i've just noticed something new [tab_Demandes removeAllObjects]; works within the appDelegate. tab_demandes has 0 objects but my app crashes right after, i dont know why yet. BUT when i do [[appDelegate tab_Demandes] removeAllObjects] in another class it crashes.

Comment: VdesmedT in fact the problem is that the dem attibutes are released in the dealloc method of the class. if i "comment" these releases i can do removeAllObjects. But i have then the attributes as leaked. It's the attributes/properties of the dem object that is the issue when i try to remove objects.

Comment: You really should read the Memory Management Document published by Apple.  I'm sure that if you well respect those rules, everything will works fine.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html